# What data structure should I use to store the dataset of my Naive Bayes classifier?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, machine-learning, naivebayes

I'm working on my own version of a Naive Bayes classifier. Right now I train it with a string for label and a hash/dictionary of features.

Here is one example of the training set I'm using:

```ruby
classifier.train(:male, { height: 6, weight: 180, foot_size: 12 })
classifier.train(:male, { height: 5.92, weight: 190, foot_size: 11 })
classifier.train(:male, { height: 5.58, weight: 170, foot_size: 12 })
classifier.train(:male, { height: 5.92, weight: 165, foot_size: 10 })
classifier.train(:female, { height: 5, weight: 100, foot_size: 6 })
classifier.train(:female, { height: 5.5 , weight: 150, foot_size: 8 })
classifier.train(:female, { height: 5.42, weight: 130, foot_size: 7 })
classifier.train(:female, { height: 5.75, weight: 150, foot_size: 9 })
```

So far I need to compute the count/total of each label, the total of each feature and the count of each feature inside each label.

There is any data structure I should use to simplify/help with these calculations?

Comment: such a beautiful question :-)

Comment: Yes, there are data structures that can simplify it. You can use a hash, a structure, or define a class, and none is better than the other. You need to experiment and find whichever works better for you. Explaining them and how to use them would require more space than we're allowed in a single answer so you need to do the ground work and try things. Ask us about specific problems when you begin implementing your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class/structure of say type person

```
class Person {
      string gender;
      float height;
      float weight;
      int foot_size;
}
```

then you can create an array containing these objects.
Person[] persons;
Add as many objects as you want with their appropriate properties and then loop through array to count each and every label.